# How can I update a paragraph tag in REACT when an input field is changed?

Tags: reactjs

I would like the paragraph tag to update the number of characters being typed into the input.  My handler prints the correct length into the console so that part works.  Here is what I have so far:

```js
class App extends Component {

  textLengthHandler = (event) => {
    let length = 0;
    if (event) {
      length = event.target.value.length
    };
    console.log("length is " + length);
    return length;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type='text' onChange={this.textLengthHandler} value={this.text}/>
        <p>length is {this.textLengthHandler()}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Don't return the length.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      textLength: 0,
      text: '',
    }
  }
  textLengthHandler = (event) => {
    let length = 0;
    const text = event.target.value;
    if (event) {
      length = text.length
    };
    console.log("length is " + length);
    this.setState({
      textLength: length,
      text: text,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type='text' onChange={this.textLengthHandler} value={this.state.text}/>
        <p>length is {this.state.textLength}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Excellent thank you!  The only problem was that calling this.state.text was not allowing input entry since the state for text was being set as an empty string but never updated.  So I found that either removing the reference to state.text worked, or using setState in the handler to update the text value as well as the length.  Much appreciated!